# Why does the following evaluate to 'hi'?

Tags: javascript, logical-operators

Why does the following evaluate to `'hi'`?

```
'hi' || true || 50
```

I'm not super new to javascript, but I'm rebeefing my knowledge by going through some old books and I for the life of me do not understand why this evaluates to `'hi'` instead of true.. Can someone explain this??

Comment: This is how `||` is defined: `x || y` means "if x is truthy return x (not "true") otherwise y".

Comment: Just [RTFM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Logical_operators)

Comment: I wonder why in your book it isn't explained.

Comment: `'hi'` is truthy. The `||` operator returns the first truthy value from left to right.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to the world of truthy and falsey values.

> If a value can be converted to true, the value is so-called truthy. If
>   a value can be converted to false, the value is so-called falsy.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators

This means that basically everything except

```
false
null
undefined
NaN
""
0
```

Will evaluate to true in `||` conditions, returning the first value that is truthy. This is sometimes used in a coalesce-like way:

```
a = a || {}
```

Which will set a to a if a is none of the values above, else an empty javascript object.

Answer (score 0):

Because 'hi' is a non-empty string literal which evaluates to true when treated as a boolean. The expression a || b || c returns the first expression which evaluates to true, in this case 'hi'.

Answer (score 0):

From [MDN (Logical Operators)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators):

Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2. Thus, when used with Boolean values, || returns true if either operand can be converted to true; if both can be converted to false, returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Hey thanks everybody for your input. Yeah, now it makes sense because I remember how the first value that evaluates to true is the one that it will evaluate to. I guess I have to do some more studying on the truthy stuff because yeah, it is simple, but in a way it is somewhat confusing at times. Thanks again!!